# How to prevent ActiveX events firing in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, activex

I am searching for a better way to disable ActiveX events from triggering in an Excel workbook (though this would apply to all Office apps with ActiveX objects).

Hopefully something similar to `Application.EnableEvents = false`, though this does not work with ActiveX.

In the below example it's trivial to use a global boolean but I have a lot of event handlers for my ActiveX objects and it would be immensely easier for something I could universally apply to temporarily disable ActiveX events. I don't really want to add an if/exit sub statement to every single one of these methods.

To demonstrate this problem, create an ActiveX combobox in a worksheet and add the following to that sheet module

```
Public initializingContent As Boolean 
Private Sub intializeAllActiveXContent()

    'this doesn't apply to activeX events :'(
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    'this could work but is not really elegant
    'change this to false to show my problem in 
    'the intermediate window (called not once but twice)
    initializingContent = True

    ComboBoxTest.Clear

    ComboBoxTest.AddItem ("item1")
    ComboBoxTest.AddItem ("item2")
    ComboBoxTest.AddItem ("item3")

    'select the top value in the box
    ComboBoxTest.value = "item1"

    initializingContent = False

    Application.EnableEvents = True

     End Sub

Private Sub ComboBoxTest_Change()
    'I really don't want to have to wrap EVERY single ActiveX method
    'with something like this for a whole variety of reasons...
    If initializingContent Then Exit Sub

    Debug.Print "do stuff I don't want to happen when intializeAllActiveXContent() runs " & _
        "but I do when user changes box"
         End Sub
```

Comment: + 1 Good Question! You had me thinking for a while :)

Comment: My code is an example for Excel. The logic remains the same for MS Word/PowerPoint. Not sure about MS Access/Project/Outlook though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not disable them? That ways you don't have to worry about their individual codes as well.

Try this

```
Sub DisableActiveXControls()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim OLEobj As OLEObject

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        For Each OLEobj In ws.OLEObjects

        If TypeOf OLEobj.Object Is MSForms.ComboBox Then
            OLEobj.Enabled = False
        End If
        Next OLEobj
    End With
End Sub
```

**Before/After ScreenShots:**

[image]

**FOLLOWUP FROM COMMENTS:**

> Also turns out this breaks hard core on objects which are grouped together but I can ungroup objects (they are no longer in "Sheet1.OLEobjects" I guess). I still don't really like this since it relies on this fact and there will be times when I do want to group objects.. – enderland 17 mins ago

To disables ActiveX Controls in a group, you don't need to ungroup them. Use this code. The below code will disable Comboboxes in a group.

```
Sub Disable_ActiveX_Controls_In_A_Group()
    Dim shp As Shape, indvShp As Shape
    Dim OLEobj As OLEObject
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    For Each shp In ws.Shapes
        If shp.Type = msoGroup Then
            For Each indvShp In shp.GroupItems
                Set objOLE = indvShp.OLEFormat.Object

                If objOLE.progID = "Forms.ComboBox.1" Then _
                objOLE.Enabled = False
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hmm. So this is an interesting approach, but unfortunately I have some objects which are not combo boxes which have variable enable/disable states to begin with - I could probably construct a dictionary of all the names and restore this but this seems a bit silly too. Is there an easy way to check if an OLEobject is a combobox? Typename() and .Type both return the same (?). I swear I've done this before somehow but I can't remember how...

Comment: +1 with my edit - `If TypeOf OLEobj.Object Is MSForms.ComboBox`. Also turns out this breaks hard core on objects which are grouped together but I can ungroup objects (they are no longer in "Sheet1.OLEobjects" I guess). I still don't really like this since it relies on this fact and there will be times when I do want to group objects..

Comment: I was editing it with that line of code :P and then I saw your edit. In fact I was giving you a link to my other post [HERE](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?505132-RESOLVED-Iterating-Through-Controls&p=3113117&viewfull=1#post3113117)

Comment: BTW you don't have to ungroup the shapes. You can directly disable them ;) I have updated the post above

Comment: Hm. This is worse than DLL hell as I think I'm going to have to wrap every single one of my `_change()` methods which updates other textboxes in some sort of protection to not start a chain reaction. Because even if I use that enable/disable in initial population of the combo boxes, every time one gets modified which affects other ones I'm going to kick the process off again... so each will have to include an `if isUpdating then exit sub` method followed by `isUpdating = true` (or disable/enable all ComboBoxes on the sheet, like you are suggesting)

Comment: Yes, even if the combo is disabled and you try to write to a combo from a textbox, the change event will fire.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38907/discussion-between-enderland-and-siddharth-rout)

Comment: My understanding of the original question (which is the same question that brought me here) is: How do you switch off events on an OLEObject.  Unless I'm missing something, I don't see an answer. Enable doesn't do it on Labels for example.  I should have twigged to this by reading MS' brilliant documentation which, more or less, explains that the Enabled Property is true if the object is enabled.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is really old. But anyone who looks this up (first hit on google) might want a simple answer:

Lets say you have a Private Sub ActiveXControl_Change() that is getting called during an Application.EnableEvents = False and you want it to skip this just go:

```
Private Sub ActiveXControl_Change()
If Application.EnableEvents = True Then
'enter you code here

End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

came across this post when searching for a similar issue.  I decided the answer posted here would not suit my situation, and came up with something else.  My approach may be useful here also.

In my workbook, I have a set of 20 (Activex) checkboxes.  These essentially filter on/off 20 categories of product to be included in a report.  There is a routine that runs each time one of these checkboxes is changed, simply by calling the routing from the CheckBox_Click routine.

Then I also have a combobox that selects various *groups* of these checkboxes.  The trouble is that when EACH of the 20 checkboxes is (un)selected by the combobox code, the calculation routine is triggered.

What I wanted was to run the calculation routine only **ONCE** at the end of the combobox, but still have it work if I change an individual checkbox manually.

My solution - put in a TRUE/FALSE code in some cell on a hidden worksheet, somewhere it's out of the way and won't interfere.

Then the CheckBox_Click code becomes (for each of the 20 checkboxes):

```
Private Sub CheckBox6_Click()
If (Sheets("Data").Range("G60")) Then
    Call RangeFind
End If
End Sub
```

The combobox code modifies this same cell, appropriately:

```
Private Sub ComboBox28_Change()

Sheets("Data").Range("G60").Value = False
Select Case Sheets("Data").Range("F50").Value
    Case "1"

    CheckBox1.Value = False
    CheckBox2.Value = False
    CheckBox3.Value = False

....

End Select

'  This turns the checkboxes back on
Sheets("Data").Range("G60").Value = True

'  This now actually calls the calculation ONCE
Call RangeFind

ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Activate

End Sub
```

Cheers,

Michael

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option:

```
Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()
    If Application.EnableEvents = True Then
        'This next line forces at least 1 of the toggle's to be selected at all 
        'times; remove it from all routines if this is not desired.
        If Not ToggleButton1.Value Then ToggleButton1.Value = True
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        ToggleButton2.Value = False
        ToggleButton3.Value = False
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ToggleButton2_Click()
    If Application.EnableEvents = True Then
        If Not ToggleButton2.Value Then ToggleButton2.Value = True
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        ToggleButton1.Value = False
        ToggleButton3.Value = False
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ToggleButton3_Click()
    If Application.EnableEvents = True Then
        If Not ToggleButton3.Value Then ToggleButton3.Value = True
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        ToggleButton1.Value = False
        ToggleButton2.Value = False
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```