# Auto-Populating a Combobox with SQL data

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I'm new to this forum, so apologies if this has already been asked and I haven’t found it or if I’m posting in the wrong place.

I have a routine that I have been using for years which populates a combobox based on data from SQL. I have a spread sheet with two comboboxes in it, the first combobox works fine and give a list of folder names straight from a SQL table. The second combobox is populated with all of the contracts that are associated with folder selected in the first combobox. However I can’t get the code to auto-populate, in order to get the combobox to update I have to select an item from the drop down list first and then the value isn’t held. I have pasted my code below:

```
Private Sub CB_Company_Change()

With Application
     .Calculation = xlManual
     .EnableEvents = False
     .ScreenUpdating = False
 End With

Dim stSQL As String, sBook As String, rst As ADODB.Recordset, k As Integer, vaData As Variant
Dim objConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim ConnectionString As String
ConnectionString = "Provider=sqloledb.1;data source=sql-server;Initial catalog=sql-db;Integrated Security = SSPI;"

Set objConn = New ADODB.Connection

sBook = CB_Book.Value
CB_Company.Clear

stSQL = "EXEC('SELECT Name FROM TABLE1 INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.ID WHERE TABLE2.NAME = ''" & sBook & "''  ORDER BY TABLE1.NAME')"

With objConn
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .Open ConnectionString
    Set rst = .Execute(stSQL)
End With

With rst
    Set .ActiveConnection = Nothing
    k = .Fields.Count
    vaData = .GetRows
End With

CB_Company.List = Application.Transpose(vaData)

objConn.Close

Set rst = Nothing
Set objConn = Nothing

bClear = True

With Application
    .Calculation = xlAutomatic
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub
```

Any help on why this might not be auto populating when run would be much appreciated.

As requested here is the code from the first combobox that gives me my book value:

```
Option Explicit
Public bClear As Boolean

Private Sub CB_Book_Change()

With Application
    .Calculation = xlManual
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Dim stSQL As String, rst As ADODB.Recordset, k As Integer, vaData As Variant
Dim objConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim ConnectionString As String
ConnectionString = "Provider=sqloledb.1;data source=SQL-SERVER;Initial catalog=SQL-DB;Integrated Security = SSPI;"
Set objConn = New ADODB.Connection

stSQL = "EXEC('SELECT NAME FROM TABLE2')"

With objConn
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .Open ConnectionString
    Set rst = .Execute(stSQL)
End With

With rst
    Set .ActiveConnection = Nothing
    k = .Fields.Count
    vaData = .GetRows
End With

CB_Book.List = Application.Transpose(vaData)

objConn.Close

Set rst = Nothing
Set objConn = Nothing

bClear = True

With Application
    .Calculation = xlAutomatic
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Where is the code that populates the second combobox? As far as I can tell, this procedure only populates `CB_Company`.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19276861/how-to-prevent-activex-events-firing-in-vba) - your event is firing over and over again because immediately after you do `CB_Company.Clear` it triggers this method again.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is the event handler for when you select a value from CB_Company, but in the code you clear that same combobox (CB_Company.clear) and repopulate it (CB_Company.List = Application.Transpose(vaData)).

Comment: Thanks Sebastiaan.Everyman, I may have this wrong but essentially what I was trying to do was. Everytime somebody clicks the combobox, it clears the current list and then goes off to SQL and repopulates the list with the results from the query. I thought by having the CB_Company.clear command before the SQL query kicks off I would be ok? Commenting out the clear comand does leave my values in the combobox but they aren't the current values based on the first combobox value.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem recently. What is happening is the "Change" method gets called frequently within itself while updating content. For example:

```
CB_Company.Clear
```

will actually cause this entire method to get called again. At some point, Excel stops processing these, leaving a blank box.

You should simply include a global variable like at the top of this module:

```
Public updatingContent As Boolean
```

Then, at the beginning of this sub include:

```
If updatingContent Then Exit Sub
updatingContent = True
```

This will prevent calls chaining.

Last, at the end of this handler, make sure to include:

```
updatingContent = False
```

to reset your method.

---

Here's your code with those changes.

```
Public updatingContent As Boolean
Private Sub CB_Company_Change()

    If updatingContent Then Exit Sub
    updatingContent = True

    With Application
         .Calculation = xlManual
         .EnableEvents = False
         .ScreenUpdating = False
     End With

    Dim stSQL As String, sBook As String, rst As ADODB.Recordset, k As Integer, vaData As Variant
    Dim objConn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim ConnectionString As String
    ConnectionString = "Provider=sqloledb.1;data source=sql-server;Initial catalog=sql-db;Integrated Security = SSPI;"

    Set objConn = New ADODB.Connection

    sBook = CB_Book.value
    CB_Company.Clear

    stSQL = "EXEC('SELECT Name FROM TABLE1 INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.ID WHERE TABLE2.NAME = ''" & sBook & "''  ORDER BY TABLE1.NAME')"

    With objConn
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
        .Open ConnectionString
        Set rst = .Execute(stSQL)
    End With

    With rst
        Set .ActiveConnection = Nothing
        k = .fields.count
        vaData = .GetRows
    End With

    CB_Company.List = Application.Transpose(vaData)

    objConn.Close

    Set rst = Nothing
    Set objConn = Nothing

    bClear = True

    With Application
        .Calculation = xlAutomatic
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    updatingContent = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Enderland, for some reason I still seem to have to click an option from the drop down list to update the combobox. So for example if I change the value in combobox 1 I then need to click combobox2 and select a value so that it repopulates with the new correct values. It's kind of doing what I want but just not automatically.