# Combo Box to Open Reports - Unable to Select items In Combo Box

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox

I have a Combo-Box that I want to use to open a list of reports I have showing.  Each report listed in the combo-box is pulled from a table (`tblObjects`) where I have the reports official names, a short two or three word description, and the type of object they are (also have forms listed in the table).  
All this works perfectly.  However, where I am having issues is "selecting" an item in the combo-box.  I'm completely unable to select anything and the "After Update" procedure I wrote (see below for code) isn't occurring.

Here are a few images of the issue:
List of the items - 
[image: Report List]
Properties for the combobox -
[image: Combobox properties]
Table Design (all fields except ID are `short text`) -
[image: Table Design]

I tried removing code from "After Update" and leave Event blank, however I still can't seem to select anything in the list.  When I click an item from the dropdown, nothing happens at all.

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub cboReports_AfterUpdate()
    DoCmd.OpenReport Me.cboReports.Value, acViewNormal
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19362398/auto-populating-a-combobox-with-sql-data) will be useful for you.

Comment: Is `Allow Edits` set to `Yes` in the Data properties of the Form itself?

Comment: Allow Edits was indeed turned to ```No```.  Dangit.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, you'll need to ensure that the **Allow Edits** property is set to **Yes** within the Data properties of the Form itself:

[image]

If this property is set to **No**, all controls on the form become read-only, regardless of whether the form has a Record Source and regardless of whether a form control is bound or unbound.