# How to prevent ComboBox Change event from being called when source list is changed

Tags: vba, excel

**TL;DR: How to prevent ActiveX ComboBox from being triggerd when adding or deleting items in the source list**

Please note that I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19276861/how-to-prevent-activex-events-firing-in-vba) and it is not the same problem or rather it does not provide a workable solution for my current project.

You can replicate the problem by creating an ActiveX ComboBox and giving it a source list range on the sheet from A1:A4, Output cell B2, then adding this code:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    MsgBox ("hello")
End Sub

Sub TestAddItem()
    Range("A4").Insert xlDown
    Range("A4").Value = "NewItem"
End Sub
```

If you run `TestAddItem`, upon getting to the "New Item" line, the `Change` event for the combo box will be triggered.

I have searched for solutions to this, but could only find the workaround suggestion to add a Boolean Variable that checks whether or not to actually proceed with the code in the change event. Here is what that would look like in my example:

```
Option Explicit
Public bMakeItHappen As Boolean

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    If bMakeItHappen Then
        MsgBox ("hello")
    End If
End Sub

Sub TestAddItem()
    bMakeItHappen = False
    Range("A4").Insert xlDown
    Range("A4").Value = "NewItem"
End Sub
```

The same thing happens if the destination of the combo box is changed. Adding or deleting items from the source range manually does not trigger the event.

Note: `Application.EnableEvents = False` has no impact on ActiveX elements! They will fire anyway (by design from Microsoft)

**How do I prevent this from happening?** As it stands, this ActiveX element is unusable, or at least I can't use it if I need to set Boolean variables everywhere in my code.

Comment: Here is one way to do it: remove the current selection / value from the ComboBox by issuing a `ComboBox1.Value = vbNullString` in the first line of `Sub TestAddItem()` (just before the rest of your code).

Comment: Just tried that and it still jumps to the Change event

Comment: B2 must be empty too (as the linked cell). https://www.dropbox.com/s/x2v6ci3lxrf13fb/StackOverflow_Question39993392.xlsm?dl=0

Comment: Ok. With B2 empty this works. Unfortunately, I have other calculations that depend on that... ofcourse I can work around that, but I'm trying to avoid the headache. You have given me at least one more workable solution thank you! PS: I can't access dropbox from my current IT setting, will do so at home though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

edited after OP's comment

since involved events *timing*, it then suffices the following code in your worksheet code pane:

```
Option Explicit

Dim bMakeItHappen As Boolean

Private Sub ComboBox1_DropButtonClick()
    bMakeItHappen = True
End Sub


Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()   
    If bMakeItHappen Then
        MsgBox ("hello") '<-- i.e. the code to be executed at "actual" combobox value change
        bMakeItHappen = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This is an elegant solution! Thank you! I will run it through some tests tonight, but in my test workbook this runs nicely!

Comment: @rohrl77, did you get through it?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. In the end it didn't work for my situation. The reason why, is that the Change Event on the worksheet is triggered AFTER the Change event for the combo box. So it ended up getting triggered anyway.

Comment: I just gave it a try. This solution works! Thanks for providing an answer.