# Sub jumping to second Sub, why

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I am trying to make it so that when you click on the Combobox it hides the unnecessary Columns so that the user can select her/his preferences and then hit the Add button to transfer the information to a print page (a separate worksheet). I had everything working well until I added the hiding columns code and now when I run my command button it jumps from the command button code to the column code and I have no clue why. if anyone could help me that would be great. Added notes to help trouble shoot inside coding. Here is the code:

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim cnt As Integer
    Dim ra As Range
    Dim a As String
    Dim y As Long
    Dim Target As Range

    'Variable list:
    'titl = title of header,
    'ra = cell address of found title name,
    'aa = simplified cell address,
    'rw = splic row address
    'clm = splic column address,
    'x = counting range,
    'cnt = counted cell numbers,
    'a = imput value 1,
    'b = imput value 2,
    'c = a and b joined
    'sa = second title address

    titl = Me.ComboBox4.Value

    MsgBox (titl)

    'this would be to go until another title
    If titl = "Caulking" Then
       e = "Frame system"
    ElseIf titl = "Frame system" Then
       e = "?*"
    ElseIf titl = "Color" Then
       e = "Caulking"
    End If

   'these to sets find the titles locations
   Set ra = Worksheets("Print page").Cells.Find(What:=titl, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
    :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False)

   If ra Is Nothing Then
      MsgBox ("Not found")
   Else
      aa = ra.Address
   End If

   rw = Range(aa).Row
   clm = Range(aa).Column

   x = aa + ":B44"

   cnt = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("Print page").Range(x), "?*")

   'setting values for Do Until loop below
   tr = Worksheets("Print page").Cells(rw, clm).Value

   'Reads cell values, maybe could change to a for loop to do larger quantities or set directly to 
    drop down menu
    a = Cells(4, 1).Value
    b = Cells(4, 2).Value
    d = Cells(4, 3).Value

    'Combines values
     c = a & " " & b

    If Worksheets("Print page").Cells(rw, clm).Value = tr Then
      Do Until Worksheets("Print page").Cells(rw, clm).Value = ""
        rw = rw + 1
    Loop
    End If

  '*(this is where is starts jumping if I comment it out it jumps on number 2 i marked and then if I 
     'comment that one out it goes to 3, if I take these out it runs, but I can't write my 
     'information to the print page)*    

     Worksheets("Print page").Cells(rw, clm).Insert Shift:=xlDown

     ' writes it to correct location
    If Worksheets("Print page").Cells(rw, clm).Value = "" Then
       Worksheets("Print page").Cells(rw, clm).Value = c '*(2)*
    Else: Worksheets("Print page").Cells(rw + cnt, clm).Value = c '*(3)*
    End If

    End Sub'''
```

(this code below is for hiding columns dependent on the combobox)

```
   Private Sub ComboBox3_Change()

    If ComboBox3 = "Frame system" Then
        Cells(7, 1).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Cells(7, 2).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Cells(7, 3).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Cells(7, 4).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Cells(7, 5).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Cells(7, 6).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Cells(7, 7).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    ElseIf ComboBox3 = "Color" Then
        Columns("A").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Columns("B").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Columns("C").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Columns("D").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Columns("E").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Columns("F").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Columns("G").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    ElseIf ComboBox3 = "Door" Then
        Columns("A").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Columns("B").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Columns("C").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Columns("D").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Columns("E").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Columns("F").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Columns("G").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Else
        Columns("A").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Columns("B").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Columns("C").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Columns("D").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Columns("E").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Columns("F").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Columns("G").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    End If

    'This macro scrolls to the top left of your spreadsheet (cell A1)
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1 'the row you want to scroll to
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1 'the column you want to scroll to

   End Sub
```

Here is a picture of my excel sheet if it helps:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8VlB.png)

Comment: I don't understand what 'it jumps on number 2' means. If you comment WHAT out? Have you stepped through the code with F8?

Comment: `Worksheets("Print page").Cells(rw, clm).Value = c` is assigning a value to some worksheet. Does the "Print page" sheet have a `Worksheet_Change` procedure in it? If so, that's where execution is "jumping"? Make `Application.EnableEvents = False` before you change a worksheet cell value if you don't want that to run that sheet's `Change` handler - and don't forget to toggle it back to `True` after you're done!

Comment: What's the source for your `ComboBox3` items?

Comment: Or it jumps to that `ComboBox3_Change` handler? Is that combobox linked to a cell value you're modifying? If so, why is the jump not expected?

Comment: The `change` event is triggered by the other code that changes it...

Comment: Consider condensing your column-hiding code.  Eg the current `Else` block is the same as `Range("A1:G1").EntireColumn.Hidden = False`

Comment: @teylyn Sorry if I didn't explain that well. When I was stepping through the first code with F8 on the lines I specify in the code as (1, 2 &3) are the lines it "jumps" from my first code the the hiding columns code, does that clarify your question? I am trying to keep it from leaving my first code all together.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I think this is probably the answer I am looking for, but I'm not sure exactly how to identify if it does have a Worksheet_Change procedure in it and where do I write that code to prevent the issue (Application.EnableEvents = False)?

Comment: @TimWilliams The source is the LinkedCell and ListFillRange in the properties menu. The LinkedCells is from a different sheet with all my tables in it and reads from a range of cells and the ListFillRange has a defined function to make make the values searchable in the drop down box. Let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon this is for your first response, I don't' know if you answered your question already, but yes it is linked to other cells in a different sheet, but not it is not being modified or changed.

Comment: @braX that's what I am thinking, but how is that happening? how can I fix it?

Comment: @TimWilliams in respects to your condensing comment: that sounds good, but how do I make it true or false separately if I do that? Maybe a for loop? Thanks for the tips.

Comment: @TimWilliams If ComboBox3 = "Frame system" Then
            Range("A1:B1").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
            Range("C1:G1").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        ElseIf ComboBox4 = "Color" Then
            Range("A1:B1").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            Range("C1").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
            Range("D1:G1").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        ElseIf ComboBox4 = "Door" Then
           Range("A1:C1").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
           Range("D1:G1").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Else
           Range ("A1:G1") > EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        End If

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I tried this and it didn't work:                                                               Application.EnableEvents = False
Worksheets("Print page").Cells(rw, clm).Insert Shift:=xlDown

' writes it to correct location
If Worksheets("Print page").Cells(rw, clm).Value = "" Then
    Worksheets("Print page").Cells(rw, clm).Value = c
    Else: Worksheets("Print page").Cells(rw + cnt, clm).Value = c
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I found this I think it's why the Application.EnableEvents isn't working. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39993392/how-to-prevent-combobox-change-event-from-being-called-when-source-list-is-chang

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. 
It was because of the Change procedure on the second code that Some of you had mentioned `Private Sub ComboBox3_Change()` for my purposes I changed that to `Private Sub ComboBox3_DropButtonClick()` and it works fine, but if you can't do that this solution [How to prevent ComboBox Change event from being called when source list is changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39993392/how-to-prevent-combobox-change-event-from-being-called-when-source-list-is-chang) is probably your next best bet.

FYI `Application.EnableEvents = False` does not work with Comboboxs, see link above for more information.

Comment: OK, can you now please take a breath, calm down and for your next question try to put the information in the question, not a barrage of comments. Please take a look around the site and learn how it works before posting another question with a beard of comments like this one.