# Adding to listbox and removing from combobox simultaneously using VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, listbox

I want to modify lists in ListBox and ComboBox so they depend on each other.

Selecting an item in Combo should add the item to ListBox.
The item must be removed from Combo.
And vice versa - removing from ListBox should add to Combo List.

```vb
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    With ComboBox1
        If .ListCount > 0 Then
            ListBox1.AddItem (.ListIndex) ' <<< it works
            .RemoveItem (ComboBox1.ListIndex)' <<< doesn't work
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_KeyUp(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = 46 Then ' <<< DEL key
        With Me.ListBox1
            If .ListIndex > 0 Then 'first item is unremovable
                ComboBox1.AddItem .List(.ListIndex)'<<<doesn't work
                .RemoveItem (.ListIndex)' <<<works
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The `.RemoveItem` triggers the `ComboBox1_Change()` event a second time -  [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39993392)

Answer (score 0):

You can see the problem when you hit Debug-button when your error comes and then hover your mouse on `ComboBox1.ListIndex`. The value -1 means no selected value.

Move your code from `ComboBox_Change` event to `ComboBox1_Click` event. Then your `ComboBox1.ListIndex` will get the correct value.